# Atributo required num input text javascript

Tags: javascript

Pretendo colocar o atributo required neste input criado em javascript

```
  // Celula 4 -Local
    // Cria um <td>
    var locall = row.insertCell(4);
    // Cria o input
    var local = document.createElement('input');
    // Input do tipo texto
    local.type = 'text';
    local.name = 'local[]';
    local.id = 'local';
    local.placeholder='Local';
    local.title = "Local";
    local.className = "form-control";
    locall.appendChild(local);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso, depois coloca a instrução:

```
local.required=true;
```

Comment: coloquei a seguir do id tal como disse e o input desaparece

Comment: Desculpa, tinha percebido de outra maneira, tenta assim.

Comment: Isso funciona, ja tinha experimentado, esqueci-me foi que o input era button e nao submit , acontece

Comment: Button ou radio button?

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="guardarEvento"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>  Guardar</button>

Comment: No problem, já alterei :)